# Laravel dusk how to click select option dynamic

Tags: php, laravel

i am having problem with clicking select option in laravel dusk

select option is not fixed I want to click from start to end

```
$browser->click('#js-select-variant-7');
$options = $browser->elements('#js-select-variant-7 option');
foreach ($options as $index => $option) {
   $option->click();
   sleep(5);
}
```

thanks all;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first define the values or get them from the database.

```
$values = [23, 24, 25, 26];
foreach ($values as $value) {
   $browser
       ->select('#js-select-variant-7', $value)
       ->pause(5000);
}
```